# I need Resources on CMB Neutrinos

Tags: cosmology, resource-recommendations, neutrinos, cosmic-microwave-background, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I am doing a research paper for upper level undergrad class on CMB neutrinos ([C$\nu$B](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_neutrino_background)). I need papers that explain CMB Neutrinos from the ground up like the main theory behind **the CMB Neutrinos and how they impact cosmology from a participial physics perspective**. I have introductory knowledge of Cosmology and QFT.

I need resources that I can cite like papers that are beginner friendly (i.e for someone who has introductory level knowledge of Quantum Field Theory but not at the level of a graduate student).

Comment: No offense, but part of the goal of a research paper assignment is for you to learn how to do literature search. You are cutting yourself short by expecting other people to do your work for you.

Comment: I have been looking but I need help with papers that are in between really technical & for people with no background.

Comment: I understand, but undergrad is not like high school. The topic is tough to begin with. Nobody knows how to measure the neutrino background, as far as I know... unless you have an idea how to boost an entire neutrino observatory to near the speed of light, that is...